Non-degeneracy in hyperplane intersections of canonical curves
Let $C$ be a smooth projective non-hyperelliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$ of genus $g = 4$. The canonical bundle $\omega_C$ induces a canonical embedding $C \longrightarrow \mathbb{CP}^3 $ such that $C$ is realized as a degree $6$ curve in $\mathbb{CP}^3$.
For any hyperplane $H$ in $\mathbb{CP}^3$, the intersection $H \cap C$ consists of 6 points, say $p_1, \ldots, p_6$. By specifying the homogeneous coordinates of $p_i$'s on $H$ (i.e. $p_i = [p_{i1}: p_{i2}: p_{i3}] \in H$), one can consider the determinant of the following $6 \times 6$ matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
p_1& p_2& p_3& p_4& p_5& p_6 \\
p_1& p_2& 0& 0& -p_5& -p_6
\end{pmatrix}
$$
My question: Can we always find a hyperplane $H$ and an ordering of the points $p_1, \ldots, p_6$ such that the determinant is non-zero?
The coefficients $(1,1,0,0,-1,-1)$ in the last row of the determinant can be replaced by any other set of coefficients $(\eta_1, \ldots, \eta_6)$, provided that no four of the $\eta_i$ are the same. The genus $4$ condition is not essential either.

One formula which may simplify the problem:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
p_1& p_2& p_3& p_4& p_5& p_6 \\
p_1& p_2& 0& 0& -p_5& -p_6
\end{pmatrix} = \;\;& 
\det (p_1 p_3 p_4) \det (p_2 p_5 p_6) -
\det (p_2 p_3 p_4) \det (p_1 p_5 p_6) \\ -&
\det (p_3 p_4 p_5) \det (p_1 p_2 p_6) +
\det (p_3 p_4 p_6) \det (p_1 p_2 p_5) 
\end{aligned}
$$

The entries of your matrix are vectors and the matrix is not square. What do you mean by the determinant in this situation?

Notice that $p_i \in H \cong \mathbb{CP}^2$, so the vectors have $3$ coordinates.

If you insist to take homogeneous coordinates on $\mathbb{CP}^3$, then the question becomes "when $\operatorname{rank}(\ldots) \neq 6$".

Edit: my answer contained an incomplete argument, here's a second attempt.
Assume by way of contradiction that for a generic hyperplane the expression $$
\begin{aligned}
D(p_1,\ldots,p_6)=\det (p_1 p_3 p_4) \det (p_2 p_5 p_6) +
\det (p_2 p_3 p_4) \det (p_1 p_5 p_6) -\\
\det (p_3 p_4 p_5) \det (p_1 p_2 p_6) -
\det (p_3 p_4 p_6) \det (p_1 p_2 p_5) 
\end{aligned}
$$
vanishes. Applying the monodromy action (using the fact that the sectional monodromy of a projective curve in characteristic zero is the full symmetric group) we obtain $D(p_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,p_{\sigma(6)})=0$ for any $\sigma\in S_6$. Using this for all $\sigma\in S_6$ we obtain 720 linear equations on the 10 terms $$M_{ijklmn}=\det(p_ip_jp_k)\det(p_lp_mp_n),\,i\le j\le k,\,l\le m\le n,\,\{1,\ldots,6\}=\{i,j,k,l,m,n\}.$$ One can get a few extra equation from the Plucker relations.
This should significantly constrain what $M_{ijklmn}$ could be (note that generically they are nonzero). Quite possibly the system has no nontrivial solutions and we arrive at a contradiction. At this point it's probably easiest to solve the system on a computer and see if there are nontrivial solution.
Another approach one can try is to set (WLOG after applying a linear transformation) $(p_1p_2p_3)=I_3$ and write $D(p_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,p_{\sigma(6)})=0$ as a system of 720 degree-3 equation in 9 variables (the coordinates of $p_4,p_5,p_6$) plus three linear equations coming from being on the same hyperplane and let a computer algebra system solve it - these parameters should be manageable. Once again if there are no solutions with all points distinct and no three on a line, the problem would be solved.

I’m having trouble understanding your answer. Could you explain what the sectional monodromy action is? Also, I don’t see why $(r_1, -r_2, 0, 0, r_5, -r_6) \in V$ since $V$ depends on the ordering of the points. Could you clarify a bit more about the third paragraph?

The sectional monodromy action essentially means that you can move the hyperplane around and return to the original position with the intersection points permuted in an arbitrary way (this is a well-known fact). Assuming your determinant vanishes for a generic hyperplane it follows that it still vanishes after you permute the points in an arbitrary way.

But why does $ (r_1, −r_2, 0, 0, r_5, −r_6) \in V$ ? I know that
$\det\begin{pmatrix}
p_1& p_5& p_3& p_4& p_2& p_6 \
p_1& p_5& 0& 0& -p_2& -p_6
\end{pmatrix} = 0$, but I don’t think that’s enough to conclude $ (r_1, −r_2, 0, 0, r_5, −r_6) \in V$.

Rewrite the above as $\det\left(\begin{array}{ll}p_1&p_2&p_3&p_4&p_5&p_6\p_1&-p_2&0&0&p_5&-p_6\end{array}\right)=0$. Then $R$ is in the span of the bottom three rows, which implies that $(r_1,-r_2,0,0,r_5,-r_6)$ is in $V$ (by changing the sign on the 2-nd and 5-th columns).

Thanks a lot! Now I fully understand your argument. :)

It looks like the collection $R_\pm$ only spans a $3$-dimensional space? $R_\pm$  has $6$ elements, and these elements are paired to $3$ groups.

You're right, fixed.

Now I don't understand why  $ (r_1, r_2, 0, 0, -r_6, −r_5) \in V$. The information about the ordering has been fully utilized in the previous step.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You're right, my argument doesn't quite work. I've edited my answer taking a slightly different approach.

For the new answer, The key idea is to switch from a single linear equation to systems of linear equations. When all the $M_{ijklmn}$ are equal, the equations are satisfied, but I can’t find any contradiction even in this simpler case (i.e., showing that these $M_{ijklmn}$ are generically not equal). I believe these $M_{ijklmn}$ are linearly independent as functions, though I don't have proof. The discussion is too long and we'd better to discuss in chat.
